# curl post never stops on loading

Tags: php, post, curl

I am unsure what the problem is.  When I run the file :

```
 <?php
   //
   // A very simple PHP example that sends a HTTP POST to a remote site
   //

   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost:8000/post.php");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

   curl_exec ($ch);
   curl_close ($ch); 
 ?>
```

the browser's displays loading spinner spins which never stops. What did I do wrong ?

The post.php file is :

```
<?php 

   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($_POST);
   echo '</pre>';
```

I tried this simple curl post using the code from http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/simplepost.html

Comment: Is your web server port listening to 8000 ?

Comment: hmmmm .. server does not seem to listen the port ...

How should I handle it ?

Comment: check the listen port in httpd.conf or virtual host configuration and change the port accordingly.

Comment: ok, the listen port seems to be running ... Doing `sudo netstat -anltp|grep :8000` gives me a list -- I have placed them in http://pastebin.com/cuv8nzCi